# Firebase user is logged out on refresh of App - React Native Expo

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

**Context**

I am aware that this question has been asked multiple times across stackoverflow, and believe me I have looked through them and tried as many approaches as I could find.

**Problem**

I have a React Native - Expo app that uses Firebase authentication. The user is logged out on every app refresh (infuriating). So, I added a listener as many other answers suggest. This was added on my login page. After every refresh, "No User" is logged in my console.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        navigation.replace('Main');
        console.log('User logged in!');
      }
      else {
        console.log("No user");
      }
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
```

As I am using V9.6.10, I have also tried the modular approach offered as an answer to a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71014978/16908525).

These answers provided in other issues seem to work for people, but none have worked for me so far. If more information is needed to solve the issue, I am happy to provide it.

This is one of the final issues of an app that I've been working on for 9 months and has remained my nemesis for a while, help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

solution is given in this post: [Best way to persist firebase login using expo go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71551192/best-way-to-persist-firebase-login-using-expo-go)

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
import { initializeAuth } from "firebase/auth"
import { getReactNativePersistence } from "firebase/auth/react-native"
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage"

const defaultApp = initializeApp(config);
initializeAuth(defaultApp, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage)
});
```