# React-native + Expo - Trouble keeping user signed with firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

It's been days since i'm trying to figure out how to keep someone signed in with firebase.
When i reload with expo, it logs me out every single time (onAuthStateChanged triggers but user is null)
Am i doing something wrong? Or the issue is related to expo?

Here is my code to give you an example:

SignIn component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Image, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import { Button, Text, TextInput } from 'react-native-paper';
import { theme } from '../../src/theme';
import { authStyle } from '../../styles/authStyle';
import { mainStyle } from '../../styles/mainStyle';
import Alert from '../Alert';
import { auth } from '../../src/Firebase';
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

const SignInScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [securePassword, setSecurePassword] = useState(true);
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState({ visible: false, message: '', type: 'error' });

  const handleSignIn = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
      setAlert({ visible: true, message: 'Connexion réussie!', type: 'success' });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
      setAlert({ visible: true, message: e.message, type: 'error' });
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  const onDismissAlert = () => {
    setAlert({ ...alert, visible: false });
  };

  return (
    <View style={mainStyle.container}>
      <View style={[mainStyle.pageContainer, {alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: '#ffffff'}]}>
        <View style={authStyle.header}>
          <Image
            style={{width: 200, height: 200}}
            source={require('../../assets/app_icon.png')}
          />
          <Text style={authStyle.headerHeadline}>Connexion</Text>
        </View>
        <TextInput
            label="Email"
            value={email}
            theme={theme} 
            mode='outlined'
            style={authStyle.input}
            outlineColor={theme.outlineColor}
            outlineStyle ={theme.outlineStyle}
            onChangeText={(email) => setEmail(email.trim())}
            autoCapitalize='none'
            left={<TextInput.Icon icon="account" />}
        />
        <TextInput
            label="Mot de passe"
            value={password}
            theme={theme}
            mode="outlined"
            secureTextEntry={securePassword}
            style={authStyle.input}
            outlineColor={theme.outlineColor}
            outlineStyle ={theme.outlineStyle}
            onChangeText={setPassword}
            left={<TextInput.Icon icon="lock" />}
            right={<TextInput.Icon iconColor={theme.colors.primary} onPress={() => setSecurePassword(!securePassword)} icon="eye" />} 
        />
        <View style={authStyle.button}>
          <Button
              mode="contained"
              onPress={handleSignIn}
              style={theme.submitButton.style}
              loading={isLoading}
              disabled={isLoading}
              labelStyle={theme.submitButton.labelStyle}
          >
              Se connecter
          </Button>
        </View>
        <Text style={{color: theme.colors.primary, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: theme.bold, marginTop: 10}}>Mot de passe oublié?</Text>
        <View style={{justifyContent: 'flex-end', flexGrow: 1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'flex-end'}}>
          <Text style={{fontWeight: theme.bold}}>Pas de compte? </Text>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SignUp')}>
            <Text style={{color: theme.colors.primary, fontWeight: theme.bold}}>Inscrivez vous</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
      <Alert visible={alert.visible} message={alert.message} type={alert.type} onDismiss={onDismissAlert} /> 
    </View>
  );
};

export default SignInScreen;
```

App.js:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Provider as PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper';
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import AppScreen from './Components/AppScreen';
import AuthScreen from './Components/AuthScreen';
import { theme } from './src/theme';
import { auth } from './src/Firebase';
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";


export default function App() {
  
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) { 
        setUser(user);
      } else {
        setUser(null);
      }
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
          {user ? (
            <AppScreen /> 
          ) : (
            <AuthScreen />
          )}
        </SafeAreaView> 
      </PaperProvider>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex:1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff"
  }
});
```

Firebase.js :

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, browserSessionPersistence, setPersistence  } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';
import { firebaseConfig } from "./firebaseconfig";
  
const firebase = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const db = getFirestore(firebase);
export const auth = getAuth(firebase);
```

And my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "musculation",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^17.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^17.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "expo": "~48.0.15",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "firebase": "^9.21.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.7",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I tried reloading the app, or close expo app and launch it again, same problem...

## Solution found

Since i wanted to keep using Expo GO because it's really convenient, i removed rnfirebase (@react-native-firebase/app and @react-native-firebase/auth).
Then i installed firebase, keeping my previous code.

I followed these instructions and everything is working fine now:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75721416/8120808

Answer (score 0):

you can remove `"firebase": "^9.21.0"` from your `package.json` and change your `firebase.js` imports:

```
import Auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth'

....

export const auth = Auth()

....


async function signInWithEmailAndPassword(
  emai,
  password
) {
  return await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email, password
  )
}
```

take a look into [expo + react-native=firebase](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/#using-react-native-firebase) documentation

EDIT:

I had this problem when using react-native-firebase: you'll need to change firebase IOS Sdk version.

To this, you'll need to add `$FirebaseSDKVersion = '9.6.0'` at the top of your `Podfile` and now you're good to go.
Don't forget this step if you run `expo prebuild --clean` or if you delete your ios folder. Maybe creating an expo plugin to handle this addition to you is a better idea in this case. [Here](https://gist.github.com/jakobo/a0a989018e12e2de0a400c9f39e887e2) a link to a plugin showing how to access and modify the podfile. You'll just need to change it to handle your needs.

If you're using expo managed workflow you'll need to add into your `app.config.js` or `app.json` file the paths to your `google-services.json` and `GoogleService-Info.plist`:

```
"expo": {
  ....

  "android": {
     ....
     "googleServicesFile": './path/to/google-services.json',
  },
  "ios": {
    ....
    "googleServicesFile": './GoogleService-Info.plist',
  }
}
```