# Firebase user logs out everytime Expo React-Native App reloads

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, firebase-authentication, expo

I built an app using Expo react-native and Firebase. The app was working correctly for a while but suddenly started giving me issues without any changes made on my part.

The user login screen works well and logs a person in correctly. I am able to access the auth.currentUser attributes after login. Whenever I reload the app simulator on Expo, the auth.currentUser value goes null. I can't seem to figure out why this is suddenly happening. The rest of the app works fine. I've tried everything I can think of and have exhausted the StackOverflow channels. I would appreciate some guidance!

Here is the code:

```
//login page - firestore does all the authentication

import { Text, TextInput, View, KeyboardAvoidingView } from "react-native"
import AppStyles from "../styles/AppStyles"
import {TextButton} from "../components/TextButton"
import { Image } from "react-native";
import {signInWithEmailAndPassword, onAuthStateChanged} from "firebase/auth";
import React from "react";
import {auth} from "../firebase"
import { useEffect } from "react";



// sign in with email and password
export function Login({navigation}){
  useEffect(() => {
    if (auth.currentUser) {
      navigation.navigate('Root')
    }
  
    const subscriber = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        navigation.navigate("Root")
      } 
    });
  
    return subscriber
  }, [])


  let [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = React.useState('');
  let [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");
  let [password, setPassword] = React.useState("");
  
  let login = () => {
    if (email !== "" && password!== "") {
        signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
          // Signed in 
            navigation.navigate('Root', {user: userCredential.user});
          // ...
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            if (error.code == "auth/wrong-password") {
                setErrorMessage("Wrong password, try again");
            } else if (error.code == "auth/too-many-requests") {
                setErrorMessage("Too many requests, please wait or reset password");
            } else if (error.code == "auth/user-not-found") {
                setErrorMessage("User not found, please try again");
            } 
            else if (error.code == "auth/invalid-email") {
                setErrorMessage("Invalid email, please try again");
            } else {
                setErrorMessage(error.message);
            }
        });    }
    }

    return (

        <View style={AppStyles.loginContainer}> 
        <KeyboardAvoidingView style={AppStyles.backgroundCover} behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : null}
        keyboardVerticalOffset={60}>
            <View style={AppStyles.loginScreen}>
                <Text style={AppStyles.textHeader}>Login</Text>
                <Text style={AppStyles.errorText}>{errorMessage}</Text>
                <TextInput 
                    style={AppStyles.input} 
                    placeholder="Email" 
                    placeholderTextColor={'#fff'} 
                    value={email}
                    onChangeText={setEmail}
                     />                
                <TextInput 
                    style={AppStyles.input} 
                    placeholder="Password" 
                    placeholderTextColor={'#fff'} 
                    secureTextEntry={true} 
                    value={password}
                    onChangeText={setPassword}
                 />
                <View style={AppStyles.rowContainer}>
                    <Text style={AppStyles.text}>Don't have an account?  </Text>
                    <TextButton size={20} text={"Sign Up"} color={'#fff'} onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Signup")} />   
                </View>
                <View style={AppStyles.rowContainer}>
                    <Text style={AppStyles.text}>Forgot your password?  </Text>
                    <TextButton size={20} text={"Reset"} color={'#fff'} onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('ResetPassword')} />   
                </View>
                <TextButton 
                    size={20} 
                    text={"Login"} 
                    backgroundColor="#83C9F4" 
                    paddingVertical={6} 
                    paddingHorizontal={12}
                    onPress={login}
                    />


            </View>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </View>

        )
}
```

Comment: Ask on the Expo website. Perhaps it is deleting cookies now?

Comment: Did you see this documentation page on [auth persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence)?

Comment: You could try removing `if (auth.currentUser) {
      navigation.navigate('Root')
    }` check as per this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71014978/20239914)

Comment: removing the if statement does not make any difference

Comment: Then the best way is to use persistence to store the user just @FrankvanPuffelen mentioned.